# c# xna move Image using two Vectors?

Tags: xna, path-finding, windows-phone-7, angles

initially image placed (0,0)th position and where ever i touch that is end position.

Now i got Start Position(0,0) and End Position(200,200).

i want to move start to end vector using angle.

If anyone now the ans please tell me.

Comment: -1 It is not clear at all what you're asking. Do you want to draw a line or determine the angle of the vector or something else?

Comment: i want to move image using two vector points/rectangle points.

Comment: So what do the two points have to do with it? Are you resizing the image, are you moving it to point B, or what?

Comment: i want to move image A position to B position with angle

Comment: You have an end position. What's stopping you from just setting the card's position to the end position? What do you mean by angle - do you want it to move steadily there or with a curve?

Comment: angle is not required now.move image A position to B position.

Comment: Then set its position to B position. If you need, say, a transition or a steady move (as if it's walking or floating slowly there) you need to specify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/move-sprite-from-ax-y-to-bx1-y1/22954#22954

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the delta between your two vectors and just move the sprite along that new vector.

```
Vector2 startPos = new Vector2(0,0);
Vector2 endPos = new Vector2(100,200);

Vector2 delta = endPos - startPos;

//see if he is at the target. Very rarely will it be Vector2.Zero, so subtract 3 to get you close. If you don't do this your sprite can bounce.
if ((delta.X > -3 && delta.X < 3)
  && (delta.Y > -3 && delta.Y < 3))
{
    sprite.Moving= false;
}

if(sprite.Moving)
{
    delta.Normalize() //you want to normalize the vector. Otherwise he will move faster diagnoally

    sprite.Position += delta *5f;  //5f is a random speed I chose. The higher this number, the faster he will move
}
```